# Debug Angular 6 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, debugging

Anyone knows what to enter in the launch.vs.json file to have debug functionality inside Visual Studio 2017, just like Visual Studio Code does with the "Debugger for Chrome" extension.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: Your question states a lot of useless information for a response, maybe you should just narrow it to a single question with just enough context to identify an answer ? And why wouldn't you use your browser to debug ? After all, javascript is ran into the browser. Any particular reason ? (Besides the dislike)

Comment: Well long story short, I think they want to use Visual Studio 2017 for they "check ins" and probably use Visual Studio Code if they want to debug their Angular code.  Having the best of both worlds.
Though I wonder if it wouldn't be possible to use only 1 tool... the tool they know and love (Visual Studio 2017).

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this question.  The examples in the VSDocs page are for a makefile.  I do have a build task setup and working but I can't seem to get a launch task working.  I can't find any examples anywhere for angular.